# What is the point of the _StructName convention in C?

Tags: c, gtk, conventions

After reading some source from the GTK+ library, I have encountered what I perceive to be a rather odd piece of code:

```
typedef struct _GtkWidgetClass GtkWidgetClass;

...

struct _GtkWidgetClass
{
    ...
};
```

What I don't understand about this code is why it isn't written like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    ...
} GtkWidgetClass;
```

I feel like I am missing something...
If someone could fill me in on as to why GTK (or for that matter, any other code) is written in this manner, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there pointers to `GtkWidgetClass` inside the struct? If so, those should be edited into the question.

Comment: @user3386109: Justs skimming over the source, it does not seem to be the case(https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkwidget.h)

Comment: [The GNOME C Coding Style guide](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/c-coding-style.html.en) doesn't say (it does say that `typedef`s should come first, but not why they "need" to be broken out), so I guess to get a "real" answer we need one of the (original?) GTK+ developers to chime in. Not holding my breath.

Comment: @Levi Ok, then the standard answer doesn't apply. Changing the subject, shouldn't the first line have a `struct` keyword in it?

Comment: @user3386109: Yes it should. Appropriate changes made.

Comment: [The GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Syntactic-Conventions) merely say "Don’t declare both a structure tag and variables or typedefs in the same declaration. Instead, declare the structure tag separately and then use it to declare the variables or typedefs". That's not quite what GTK+ is doing. Btw, I so dislike coding standards without motivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a strict coding standpoint, it has no purpose. However, in header files it can serve as a type of interface definition, which list the "public" interface of GTK+. By the way, this style follows other GNU libraries.

Anyway, I think we can safely say, that with modern C compilers and tools, it does not really make too much sense, but GTK+ is not really a new library, so it can contain some archaic coding conventions.

Answer (score 4):

The first case allows you to use the (typedefed) name of the `struct` for a member:

```
typedef struct _node node;

struct _node
{
    int value;
    node *next; /* valid */
};
```

---

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    node *next; /* not valid (unknown type name ‘node’) */
} node;
```

Comment: Ahh this makes a bit more sense now. I guess in the case I posted, this was just a continuity thing (GtkWidgetClass contains no instances of GtkWidgetClass). +1